# Unable to get current time using javascript

Tags: javascript

Displaying only today's date unable to get time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
</script>

<li id="date"></li>
```

Comment: Why not read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript?

Comment: @JJJ I need to display as well how the date is displaying in the same format time should be displayed

Comment: I have no idea what that means, or what your actual problem is. Show an example of what you want to see.

Comment: @JJJ need to display present date and time

Comment: Have you read any [documentation for `Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript) that would show what methods to use to get minutes and hours? Have you Googled for "show current time in javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code to extract hours, minutes and seconds and then append them to the string. See below.

```js
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
hour = n.getHours();
min = n.getMinutes();
sec = n.getSeconds();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
```

```html
<li id="date"></li>
```

Comment: Its working thank you

Comment: Getting one issue if the time is 2 hours 3 mins 3 seconds it is displaying as 2:3:3 it should display as 02:03:03.It should display two digits only

Answer (score -2):

Your code is perfekt, but you didn't checked the runtime problems.

If you run your js code after declaring of the div it works.
Because, the javascript search after a id that not exits on the dom. If you change the sort of code the runtime problem will be removed.
[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/USkrWtSFkbvb0jOlzgpJ?p=preview)

```
<li id="date"></li>    
<script type="text/javascript">
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
</script>
```

[Problem Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

If you want you can use moment libery of date/time it very useful.
[Moment JS Libary](https://momentjs.com/)